# Unable to push into public repository in Bitbucket cloud

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-cloud

I have been using bitucket server and recently an external vendor had setup a repository on bitbucket cloud. We have a corporate proxy as well.

I am having issues pushing changes to public repo or cloning private repo on bitbucket cloud.

**Issues:**      **( Environment: Bitbucket cloud)**
1) I am able to clone a public repository, but unable to push anything to it.
When pushing I get password prompt and then the error.

Password for 'https://myid@bitbucket.org':
***I entered the password ( I made sure I am entering the correct password)***
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myid@bitbucket.org/myid/testpublicrepo.git/'

2) When I try to clone a private repository, I am getting same error
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myid@bitbucket.org/myid/testrepopvt.git/'

**Things I have tried:**

1)  I tried  curl -L bitbucket.org and responses are coming.

2) I have entered 104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org in /etc/hosts file.

3) I tried repeating these steps on a repository in bitbucket server and it works like a charm. Here also password is prompted during clone and push operation, but works fine when i enter the password.

```
git config --global user.name "Username"    
git config --global user.email "My Email Id"    
git clone http://user@bitucketserver:7990/scm/jen/test.git      
git init    
git add --all    
git commit -m "Initial Commit"    
git remote add origin http://user@bitucketserver:7990/scm/jen/test.git    
git push -u origin master
```

I assume if cloning is happening on bitbucket cloud repo, then proxy is setup correctly. 
Kindly let me know if you think something is not done correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your password has any special characters? (@,!,...)

Comment: No, just the alphanumeric one.

Comment: What git version do you have? On which OS are you?

Comment: git version-  2.14.1
Operating system : CentOS

Comment: Do you have any credential helper in place, which might have cached the credentials already? Check the output of `git config credential helper` from within your repo.

Comment: This is what I got when I executed the command - git config credential helper                                                                                                           
"error: key does not contain a section: credential"

To clarify, can we use a ssh key to push changes onto repo in bitbucket cloud?    .                                                                                                  .  
If so , should I add the key as access keys in repository or ssh keys in my profile

Comment: Sorry, I meant `git config credential.helper`, and that is for http(s) URL only. You could try through SSH, if `ssh -T yourServer` does work (meaning you have added your public key to your server account profile)

Comment: Let's not rule the proxy out just yet. You don't need to provide credentials to clone a public repo, but you do if you want to push to a public repo or do anything at all with a private repo. Your local Bitbucket Server instance may also be exempt from the proxy (since it's inside your local network).

What do you get for `git config --get http.proxy` on the affected system?

Comment: @JimRedmond : For git config --get http.proxy, nothing is returned. I think this variable is not set.

Comment: @VonC : Tried git config credential.helper &no output is seen. I checked ssh -T git@bitbucket.org and nothing happened and seems like it is waiting for server to respond. Also tried ssh -T git@mylocalbitbuckserver and I am being prompted with password to login.contents of git config file inside repo is below

[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://myid@bitbucket.org/myid/testpublicrepo.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master

Comment: So you have a corporate proxy, but you haven't told Git how to use it?

Comment: I have tried setting that as well using this command "git config --global https.proxy username:password@myproxy:port" . I still get the same error "remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed"
One of the comments I saw was proxy is stripping the Authorization header and thatswhy I am able to clone public repo, but unable to push.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident your username/password is correct, then most likely it's a permission problem on the BitBucket Cloud repository itself.

Check that your BitBucket Cloud user account has Write or Admin access in the Repository settings, AND that branch permissions/restrictions also allow your user to push to the branch you are trying to push. Both of these must be true or the push will fail with an authorization error similar to the one shown.